How to Check if an NFT Belongs to a Specific Collection in Solana with mpl_token_metadata?
I'm working on verifying whether a given NFT's mint address belongs to a specific collection on Solana.  In examples I’ve seen, mpl_token_metadata::state::Metadata was used for this purpose, as shown in the following function:
fn nft_belongs_to_collection(
    nft_mint: &Pubkey,
    collection_mint: &Pubkey,
    metadata_account_info: &AccountInfo,
) -> Result<bool> {
    let metadata: Metadata = Metadata::from_account_info(metadata_account_info)?;

    if let Some(collection) = metadata.collection {
        if collection.key == *collection_mint && collection.verified {
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
    Ok(false)
}


However, in the latest version of the mpl-token-metadata crate, the state module no longer exists, and Metadata::from_account_info is not available.
My Question:
How can I determine if an NFT belongs to a specific collection within a Solana program using the updated mpl-token-metadata library?
Specifically:

How can I fetch and deserialize the metadata account in the latest version of the library?

What is the correct approach to check if an NFT's mint address is part of a specific collection, given the changes in mpl-token-metadata?



If you are using anchor, you will be able to fetch this from the deserialized account in the collection field key,
ref: https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/types/struct.Collection.html
You can however deserialize this account manually to the details.
I am doing this in anchor but the same method should work with native programs
pub fn deserialize_md(ctx: Context<DeserializeMD>, collection_mint: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        let data = ctx.accounts.metadata.data.try_borrow_mut().unwrap();
        let metadata = Metadata::deserialize(&mut data.as_ref());

        if let Ok(md) = metadata {
            let collection = md.collection.unwrap();
            if collection.verified && collection.key == collection_mint {
                // ! add logic here
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    }


Thank you so much
